# Форма при отправке не переходит по action на сторонний сайт

Tags: php, html, form, redirect, action

```js
 <form action=”https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/api/partners/v1/lightweight/create” method=”post” >
<input name=”shopId” value=”test_online” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”showcaseId” value=”test_online” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”promoCode” value=”default” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”sum” value=”99000.00” type=”hidden”>
<input name=”itemName_0” value=”Apple iPhone 7 256 GB Onyx” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemQuantity_0” value=”1” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemPrice_0” value=”59000.00” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemCategory_0” value=”iPhone Apple” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemName_1” value=”Apple iPhone 6S 128GB Onyx” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemQuantity_1” value=”1” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemPrice_1” value=”40000.00” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”itemCategory_1” value=”iPhone Apple” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”customerEmail” value=”customer@tinkoff.ru” type=”hidden”/>
<input name=”customerPhone” value=”+79031234567” type=”hidden”/>
<input type=”submit” value=”Купи в кредит”/>
</form>
```

При переходе форма не отправляет на сайт в указанный в action формы

А просто добавляет `мойсайт.ру/"https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/api/partners/v1/lightweight/create" + параметры.`

Поможете?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас не правильный символ кавычек `”`. Это какие-то стилистические кавычки, может из ворда взятые или что-то вроде того.

Используйте нормальные кавычки " `(SHIFT + 2)` в русскоязычной раскладке или `SHIFT + русская Э` в англоязычной.

Ещё можете добавить к форме `target="_blank"`, чтобы переход на сайт тинькова был в новом отдельном окне.

Рабочий код:

```html
<form action="https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/api/partners/v1/lightweight/create" method="post">
  <input name="shopId" value="test_online" type="hidden" />
  <input name="showcaseId" value="test_online" type="hidden" />
  <input name="promoCode" value="default" type="hidden" />
  <input name="sum" value="99000.00" type="hidden">
  <input name="itemName_0" value="Apple iPhone 7 256 GB Onyx" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemQuantity_0" value="1" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemPrice_0" value="59000.00" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemCategory_0" value="iPhone Apple" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemName_1" value="Apple iPhone 6S 128GB Onyx" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemQuantity_1" value="1" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemPrice_1" value="40000.00" type="hidden" />
  <input name="itemCategory_1" value="iPhone Apple" type="hidden" />
  <input name="customerEmail" value="customer@tinkoff.ru" type="hidden" />
  <input name="customerPhone" value="+79031234567" type="hidden" />
  <input type="submit" value="Купи в кредит" />
</form>
```